# Oracle 11g and .NET ODP character set conversion

Tags: oracle, set, character

We have Oracle 11g database with EE8ISO8859P2 character set. This character set can’t be changed, i.e. it must stay as it is.

However the data that will be inserted and read from the database will be from another character set: CL8MSWIN1251.

We are using .NET and ODP. One possible approach is manual transliteration in the .NET application itself.

Is the following scenario with Oracle 11g, .NET and ODP feasible?

1. Data is stored on the server into database with EE8ISO8859P2 character set encoding.
2. ADO.NET ODP driver connects to the database and retrieves the character data as opaque bytes which are further decoded in the .NET client by using the mapping: CL8MSWIN1251=>CLR Unicode.

We have tried with NLS_LANG environment variable but that did not solve the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `ODP` instead of `ODC`.

I don't think your proposal is a good idea. Of course, it is always possible to "cheat" the database character inside your .NET application. But imagine a DBA has to analyze an issue on the database. Usually he will use a tool like SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, or similar. Or what happens when another tool access the database, e.g. for reporting purpose. All these topics will not work.

An Oracle database actually has two character sets, the "normal" one the the "national" one. Perhaps you can use the second characters set by using `NVARCHAR` or `NCHAR` datatypes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes ODC was a typo. The database character set, the normal one and the national, can't be changed, i.e. it is not an option.
Do you have some proposal how can we cheat the database character set inside .NET application (not manual transliteration, but driver and environment configuration)